# Elasticsearch suddenly not reachable/running anymore

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

A few days ago I used elasticsearch together with jhipster. I was able to start elasticsearch by running the backend of the jhipster application. (./mvnw in my case)

Suddenly, without having made any changes to the application itself, elasticsearch isn't reachable anymore. Neither curl nor normal http requests work. Trying to achieve the same in a newly generated jhipster application ends with the same result. There are no logs present under target/elasticsearch/logs. (The folder does not even exist)

Therefore I assume something is preventing elasticsearch from starting up.

How can I figure out what's creating this problem?

Comment: What do your Elasticsearch logs say?

Comment: Have you checked that there isn't another application listening on same port than embedded elasticsearch ? have you tried rebooting ?